# Making a series stationary, 1st and 12th order differencing

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, stationarity, seasonality

I know how to make a series stationary if it has a seasonal trend or a linear trend, I would do 1st order differencing. But the bit I don't understand is how make a series stationery if it has both a seasonal trend and a linear trend? I've done a 12th order difference to remove the seasonal component and then taken a first order difference to remove the linear trend. My result looks to be stationary. How is it this works as when taking a 12th order difference the result is not a linear trend? And only after differencing the result the result is stationary?

[image: 12th order difference][image: Difference of 12th order.]

Comment: Why don't you post a time series that has these characteristics . It can be a real time series or something you have simulated.

Comment: Hi irishStat, I've posted a more complete description of the project, which now includes graphs and my problem at hand.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  How it is possible that two successive differencing operations can create a stationary-looking time series?

Comment: If you have a series which has both a trend and a seasonal effect, then you would need a first order difference to elimate the trend and a 12th order difference to eliiminate seasonality if the data is monthly. The rcode might look something like diff(diff(name, lag=1,diff=1), lag=12,diff=1). So I'm just confused at how the 12th order difference doesn't leave a positive trend.